# Pass URL Arguments to Tor Browser in Windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I would like to be able to test out some web pages that I am making with the Tor Browser (v3.6.6) to make sure that they work with it. I can currently take the URL of the page I am working on and paste it into Tor Browser's address bar.

I would like to configure my web developer environment (in this case, Visual Studio) to open the pages in Tor automatically. Is there any way to do this in Windows? (I have seen information on how to do it in Linux, but that doesn't help me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've configured Tor already, you can just call "firefox.exe" from the Browser folder of TBB.

```
firefox.exe "http://www.google.com"
```

Put this command into visual studio configuration and it will automatically load it.

Comment: By "configured Tor," do you mean if I've gone through the wizard that appears the first time I start Tor browser?

Comment: I tried it, and, strictly speaking, this is the answer to my question. In Tor 3.6.x, I can call "firefox.exe" and pass arguments to it. It's even easier in Tor 4.x, because there is only one executable. So, while this answers my question about passing arguments to Tor Browser, it appears that Tor can't view pages on the "localhost:" server. Thanks, @Lizbeth for your help.

Comment: I don't think this advice is any safe. Users are advised to not launch firefox directly